# Changing CultureInfo of Main thread from worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, globalization, cultureinfo

Is it possible to change CurrentUICulture of main thread when event is raised in worker thread?

Code for ilustration:

```
static void Main()
{
   //do something

  Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
  workerThread.Start();

  //do something
}

void DoWork()
{
   ConnectDatabase();

   //do some work

   ChangeLanguage(lang);

}

void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
{
   //this line changes Culture only  for worker thread
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);

}
```

Comment: Could you indicate _why_ a thread has to change properties of the main thread? This sounds like a very bad design. Maybe better to step back and look for a better solution to the actual problem.

Comment: Its WinForm client application and it has  user settings stored in a database. Worker thread connects database (it takes some time). After successful connection, application should set language according to the user settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its WinForm client application and it has user settings stored in a database. Worker thread connects database (it takes some time). After successful connection, application should set language according to the user settings.

When your Thread is finished it could  use `MainForm.Invoke(helperMethod)` and then the helperMethod is run on the main thread and can set the Culture safely.

A [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) would make it even easier. It has a Completed event that runs on the main Thread.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need the worker thread to know about the main thread, so it could do:

```
mainThread.CurrentUICulture = ...;
```

However, that strikes me as a fairly dangerous idea... the main thread could be half way through retrieving some resources, for example.

Why not have a method which you can invoke in the main thread (e.g. using `Control.Invoke` if you're using Windows Forms - the context isn't clear here) which will allow the main thread to change its own culture in a controlled way, reloading resources as necessary etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke cross-thread callback, if you your application is WinForms app, then you can use [ISyncronizedInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) (it is implemented by any WinForms control).

If not you can use cross-context callback:

```
static void Main()
{
  Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWork));
  workerThread.Start(Thread.CurrentContext);
}

void DoWork(object state)
{
   ConnectDatabase();

   //do some work

   ((Context)state).DoCallBack(() => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ...);
}
```